# Extracting year from a string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have the strings in the format of:

```
AM Kaplan, M Haenlein - Business horizons, 2010 - Elsevier
A Lenhart, K Purcell, A Smith, K Zickuhr - 2010 - pewinternet.org
```

And would like to extract the year.

I was using:

```
year = year.Substring(year.LastIndexOf(",") + 1, year.LastIndexOf("-") - 1).Trim();
```

But got length errors and this would also break when the last index needed is '-' for the start of the substring instead of ','.

How can I extract the year properly?

Comment: First, Substring takes the start index and the length, not the start index and the ending index. Second, you need to clearly define your parameters here. Your example won't work for the second string. Are there other potential permutations?

Comment: Regular expressions come to mind.

Comment: There are others but those are the two permutations that occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following expression verifies string for `authors - optionalPublisher year - site` format:

```
var s = "AM Kaplan, M Haenlein - Business horizons, 2010 - Elsevier";

var match = Regex.Match(s, @".+ - .*(\d{4}) - .+");
if (match.Success)
{
     var year = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: Safest solution here. It's probably fair to assume that 4-digit numbers won't arbitrarily appear in the list of authors.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'A Lenhart, K Purcell, A Smith, K Zickuhr - 2010 - pewinternet.org'
```

If the year is always in the last element of the string separated by commas and is always between two hyphens, then you could do something simple like

```
last = s.split(',')[-1]
year = int(last.split(' - ')[1])
```

`s.split(delimiter)` transforms the string into a `list` object, where each element in the list is a substring of `s` partitioned by `delimiter`, which in your case are commas and hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the year appears as the last element of the comma-delimited string, but it doesn't always fall between 2 hyphens.  What it looks like it that it appears before the last hyphen.  If that is always the case, this works:

```
    int ExtractYear(string delimitedString)
    {
        // Only works if Year appears in the last split field of the delimitedString
        // and also Year is the 2nd to last sub-field of that last field.
        var fields = delimitedString.Split(new char[] {','});
        var subfields = fields.Last().Split(new char[] {'-'});
        int result = 0; 
        // -1 denotes bad value
        return int.TryParse(subfields[subfields.Length - 2], out result) ? result : -1;
    }
```